# NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 23

Tags: ios, xml-parsing

Anyone have any additional details on the possible cause of a "NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 23"?  The only info that I can find is: NSXMLParserEntityReferenceMissingSemiError in the header file.  It appears that it is related to the possible fact that "Entity reference is missing semicolon" - which I can't see how applies in my example of properly formed XML.

Thanks.

Comment: have you validate your xml with a xml validator? http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that a `"&"` had snuck into my XML.  I replaced with `"&amp;"` and everything worked fine.